# Java code flow parser analizer for all API Calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Is there a special tool or Parser project where I can find the API calls for each Controller in my source code?

For example, I have a user/createUser controller method, I want to find out if this method calls other services with FeignClient or RestTemplate in service classes.